# npm command not found Macbook Air M1

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded the lts version from here https://nodejs.org/en/download/ for my macbook air m1. When i open up the terminal and search for node it shows me the correct version. However, when I type in npm or npm --version the command is not found. Do you guys have to solution for it. Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Macbook M1. Did you install the downloaded file? Try to reboot. Usually if `npm -v` or `node -v` doesn't return the version, it means that something with the installation is corrupted. If the restart doesn't work, try to install it again.

Comment: I tried restarting my computer but still npm cannot be found. I also did uninstall node completely and reinstall but still npm cant be found.

Comment: You are downloading the "macOS Installer (.pkg)" version, correct?

Do you encounter any problems during the installation of the nodejs?